# What does this Angular CLI command do?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

What does this command do in Angular command line?

```
npx ng g s weather --flat false
```

From Book:

Angular 6 for Enterprise Ready Web Applications
pg 61

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creates a service named weather.  The --flat default is false, so it's not needed.
--flat: boolean, default false, generate component files in src/app instead of src/app/site-header